# Connection of database using PyMySQL in Python 3.x

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, pymysql

Getting connection error in PyMYSQL:

**Error**

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='pymysql')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

**code**

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='pymysql')

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT Host,User FROM user")

print(cur.description)

print()

for row in cur:
   print(row)

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use capital 'C' in pymysql.Connect.

```
conn = pymysql.Connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='pymysql')
```

The above statement should work. It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

You've called some other module "pymysql". Look for a file named "pymysql.py" and rename it, and remove any associated .pyc file.

Answer (score 0):

The connection was successful in this code:

```
con=pymysql.connect('localhost','root','root','mydb27')
```

But now I am following this code:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='kanha@12345',
                             database='mydb23',
                             charset='utf8mb4')
cur1=connection.cursor()
cur1.execute("select * from emp where city='hyd'")
```

Comment: What part is the correct answer? I'm confused as to what the answer is.

Answer (score 0):

I had that error, due I named my py file as *select.py*. I don't know how you named it but you could try changing the name file.